# Evitar insertar en una tabla mediante PHP/SQL si este registro ya existe

Tags: php, sql, insert

Cuando preciono en mi "*Submit*" ejecuto un insert "*Insert*" que guarda una serie de registros "`X[i+]`":

```
id,_Nombre,__fecha
```

a

```
id,_Nombre,__fecha
1__Juan_____22/12/2000
2__Fulano___22/12/2000
3__Aldo_____22/12/2000
```

Deseo que si presiono otra vez mi *submit* para guardar el registro actual de ese mes no me lo permita si ya ya existen estos.

Mi linea de inserciones:

```
include "conn.php"; ($conn)
$query = "INSERT INTO datosp (nombres,fecha) SELECT ('$nombres',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM usuarios;
sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) or die (print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Creo que te faltan cerrar comillas en tu insert

Comment: En tu base de datos y en tu tabla, dicho campo debería ser unique para que sea el gestor quien evite duplicidad de datos

Comment: "Levi Arista", heheh ese fue mi error al subir una linea de codigo en este foro trato de hacerla lo mas consiso posible (en mi tabla tengo mas de 3 datos a agregar en realiudad son 52 X_x) y en este caso olvide poner las comillas

Comment: Alfredo si pero si es unique no e permitiria guardar la misma fecha para todos en el primer insert , y si me manda error de sql se ve feo. pineso que lo ideal seria poner algo como if  (!$fecha=fecha_tablaB == fecha_ultimo registro)  insertar else error o algo asi

Comment: Bueno podrías intentar primero hacer un select de sese registtro, si no devuelve nada haces el insert

Comment: tu sentencia seria algo asi: INSERT INTO usuarios(Nombre)
SELECT 'nombre'
FROM usuarios
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT nombre FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = ‘nombre_post_php’ LIMIT 1)

Comment: te falta el WHERE NOT EXISTS

Comment: Como indica @AlfredoPaz esos campos deberian tener un indice unique compuesto. En este caso un unique compuesto por varios campos, es decir que si los 2 campos conjuntamente ya existen no se pueda repetir. Deberias aplicar algo como `ALTER TABLE tu_tabla ADD UNIQUE unique_index ('campo1', 'campo2', 'campoN');`

Comment: Alfredo me fue muy util tu respuesta , excactamente como la mencionaste :D te agradesco mucho y podrias ponerlo en respuests para que pueda colocarle flechita verde :) como resuelto ? gracias!

Comment: hecho @claus ya te respondí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Puedes controlar el evitar el ingreso de registros duplicados directamente desde el gestor de bases de datos:**

Si por ejemplo apenas vas a crear tu tabla, lo haces así

```
edad INT UNIQUE NOT NULL
```

Al utilizar el atributo `UNIQUE` será el propio motor el que verifique cuando intentes hacer un alta, si ese registro ya existe; en caso afirmativo este `CONSTRAINT` que pide valores únicos se activará y te devolverá un error que dice mas o menos así:

> ## 1062 - Duplicate entry '' for ........

¿Qué pasa si ya tengo la columna creada?

Debes hacer lo siguiente

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD UNIQUE edad_unique (edad);
```

Si vas a declarar como únicos a distintas columnas de tu tabla lo puedes lograr del modo siguiente

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD UNIQUE datos_unique (edad, nombre, email);
```

*ACLARACIONES*

1. Con la sentencia `ALTER`, modifico algún elemento de la estructura original de la tabla
2. Con el operador `ADD` indico que voy a agregar algo nuevo a la declaración de esa columna
3. cuando agrego `UNIQUE` le indico que los valores o columnas que voy a declarar después serán únicos